# All jQuery mobile events firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple use case on my index page.

```
        <script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>

         <script>
                 $("body").on("swipeleft", function(event) {
                alert('hello');
                /*window.location.href = "html/first.html";*/             
            });
       </script>
```

For some reason this event is firing 2 times. Now I am sure I haven't binded another event on the body tag as this is the first page. I have tried other simple events also like touchstart etc. They all are firing twice. What am I doing wrong ?

Update :-

I have modified the answer I marked as correct in the following way and it worked. The events on this page are not firing twice.

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
            <script>
                 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
                       $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
                       $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                       $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = false;
                       $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
                       $.mobile.loadingMessage = '' ;                 
                  });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @Floradu88 : You are right sorry for that. I was trying out a few solutions but haven't got the exact answer yet. But I will mark the one I am working on .

Comment: You should mark only correct answers, do not mark an answer which is not correct

Comment: Yes, but the one I have marked correct worked with some changes to it. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are few ways of avoiding this problem. Like [CodeJack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184902/codejack) told you this is a know issue but it is not an error, mainly because of the **jQM** unique way of handling pages.

- Easiest one is to unbind an event before binding it again, like this:

  ```
  $("body").off().on("swipeleft", function(event) {
      alert('hello');
      /*window.location.href = "html/first.html";*/             
  });
  ```

  In case you have other events bound to same object use this:

  ```
  $("body").off("swipeleft").on("swipeleft", function(event) {
      alert('hello');
      /*window.location.href = "html/first.html";*/             
  });
  ```
- There is an alternative to using event bind/unbind, live/die and on/off. Instead of unbinding before you bind it again use **jQuery event filter**, it can be used to identify if event is already been bind. Don't forget to download it from link posted below (it is not a standard part of **jQM**).

  http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

  This is my usage example:

  ```
  $('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){ 
      //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something 
  });
  ```

  I am using each because my carousel div has many inner blocks but principle is the same. If #carousel inner div elements don't have click event add them that event. In your case this will prevent multiple event binding.

Additional solutions can be found **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/)**.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using document ready event to attach events to body. Also you may want to attach an event **only once** to body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").off().on("swipeleft", function(event) {
        alert('hello');          
    });
});
```

In case you have other events bound to same object use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").off("swipeleft").on("swipeleft", function(event) {
        alert('hello');          
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue...i found it to avoid by moving the js code inside `<head>` tag..i donno the reason..but that avoided the problem...